# PhoneGap or Flex

Tags: apache-flex, cordova

I want to build my first mobile app.

I am wondering if I should use Flex or PhoneGap.

I'm not a strong developer, but have great skills in actionscript 3 -- which is why I would consider using Flex.

I don't know too much about PhoneGap, at all, but my CSS and HTML4/5 skills are excellent, and my jquery/javascript is ok.  Is this really all that PhoneGap requires or would I need database skills as well?

I read about FlashBuilder, but from what I understand, and correct me if I'm wrong, I would need to code in one of the Eclipse-based plugin languages: Java, C++, Ruby, COBOL, etc.  I don't know any of these, so if I can stick to actionscript 3 with Flex or PhoneGap with HTML/Javascript/CSS, then that would be ideal.

Lastly, if I take the time to really learn Flex, do you think it will eventually fade away and be replaced with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decide to go with Flex, then you'll be coding in a combination of actionscript and MXML. No knowledge of Java (or C++, Ruby, Cobol, etc) is required. Check out Adobe's Flex in a Week training course -- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html -- it'll give you a good idea of what's involved with flex development.

As to Flex's long-term viability, Flex was recently turned over to the Apache Foundation (read more here http://www.riagora.com/2012/01/apache-flex-and-the-community/).

Comment: Update: The [first version of Apache Flex](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/download.html) has now been released.

Answer (score 2):

The flash packager works great, its simple to use and there is no native language skills needed. The problem is that if you want to access specific native features, say the camera or things like that you are out of luck.

Phonegap is a bridge between HTML/CSS/JS and native code. You can code your app as you would a web app and then hook it up with the phonegap API to make native system calls. You do not need to have extensive knowledge of the native code ( obj-c & java ) but it does come in handy if you know a little, or at least are willing to learn.

I've used both, and they both work great, but phonegap is the better cross platform solution - If you try to deploy the Flash packaged Android app your users will have to download the adobe runtime before they can run your app..

Comment: I wouldn't say you're out of luck with Flex and native features. Adobe provides a variety of native extensions that are accessible from an AS3/Flex mobile app. You can even write your own extensions if the provided ones don't suffice. Check http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was leaning toward PhoneGap and then I read that since PhoneGap uses the native capabilities of each supported mobile platform, I will need to install the appropriate native SDKs for each platform that I want to deploy to.
In the case of iOS, I require an Apple Mac computer.  I don't have a Mac -- and I can't afford to buy a second computer to create an app.  Flex it is!

Comment: There are already services which allow you to package an app for iOS, even if you don't own a Mac. One of them is PhoneGap:Build https://build.phonegap.com/